# NSURLProtocol canInitWithRequest: only works for certain requests

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, macos

I have a WebView that I want to intercept and modify certain requests from various sites.  I am doing the exact same modification to each of the intercepted requests regardless of which site it comes from.  It works perfectly for every site except one, for seemingly no reason.  Here is my code:

In my ResourceLoadDelegate

```
- (NSURLRequest *)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource
{
    //predicates
    const NSPredicate *site1Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like \"/*predicate1*/""];
    const NSPredicate *site2Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like \"/*predicate2*/""];
    const NSPredicate *site3Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like \"/*predicate3*/""];
    const NSPredicate *site4Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like \"/*predicate4*/""];
    const NSPredicate *site5Predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like \"/*predicate5*/""];

    //predicate arrays
    const NSArray *songPredicates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:site1Predicate, site2Predicate, site3Predicate, site4Predicate, site5Predicate, nil];

    //site is an int with its defined in an enum
    if ([[songPredicates objectAtIndex:site-1] evaluateWithObject:request.URL.host])
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest* newRequest = [request mutableCopy];
        [InterceptionProtocol setProperty:self forKey:@"MyApp" inRequest:newRequest];
        dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            /* Do stuff */
        });
        return newRequest;
    }
    return request;
}
```

In InterceptionProtocol.m

```
+ (BOOL) canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request
{
    id delegate = [NSURLProtocol propertyForKey:@"MyApp" inRequest:request];
    if (delegate) NSLog(@"Can init: %@", request);
    return (delegate != nil);
}
```

For some reason this works perfectly for everything except site 4.  I have stepped through the code and I know that the predicate is matching correctly.  I do not know how this could work for the other sites but not this one.  Any ideas?

**Edit**

Full source code can be found here:
http://github.com/garrett-davidson/iLikeMusic

Comment: did you face any warning or error

Comment: what is your deployment target. which version this not work either all  the version or any specially like iOS 5, iOS 6...

Comment: Where do you call `+[NSURLProtocol registerClass:]`?

Comment: @iDev nope, no errors or warnings, and the target is OSX 10.9

Comment: @AaronBrager I call that in my button to load the website.  I am certain that it fires before any of this is sent

Comment: Are you doing anything with the NSURLRequest on the priority default queue?  NSURLProtocol isn't threadsafe.

Comment: And, shouldn't it be `id delegate = [self propertyForKey:@"MyApp" inRequest:request];` (`self` in a class method refers to the class).

Comment: @AaronBrager no I never touch the NSURLRequest on anything but the main queue.  I will try making the `self` change and see what happens, though I do not believe it will make a difference.

Comment: @AaronBrager just tried that change and still no luck :/

Comment: You should include the working/non-working data you're handling

Answer (score 1):

Seems the issue is with `predicate4` not matching `site4`. Your note on stepping through code and it matching correctly is confusing - if this were the case, everything would be working, won't it?

Could it be that instead you manually tested the url you expect against the predicate - but instead there is slight difference in what you get during real run (say due to URL encoding - there being spaces or `/` or `?` which are `+` or `%` encoded). Put `NSLog` before `evaluateWithObject:` to see what exactly comes in `request.URL.host`?

Comment: No I stepped through the code in the real run.  I agree that it is confusing, which is why I posted it here.  It matches correctly and the property is set, but for some reason `canInitWithRequest:` never returns true for this site

Comment: Humpf, humpf. Is it possible that `webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:` gets invoked multiple times because of redirect from the server side? And the predicate matched the first time but there is another call afterwards. Maybe you want `webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource` instead

Comment: If that were the case, shouldn't my `NSLog` still fire?  Because the initial request should still get the property set

Answer (score 1):

Then, we must register this protocol on you App Delegate’s -(

```
BOOL)application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [NSURLProtocol registerClass:[ChromeBrowserURLProtocol class]];
...
```

source:[customizing-uiwebview-requests-with-nsurlprotocol](http://eng.42go.com/customizing-uiwebview-requests-with-nsurlprotocol/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, NSURLProtocol isn't supporting streaming connections, and I believe this is the difference. Compare to the rdio stream (returning 206)

[image]

to say, Pandora, which returns completed responses (200).

[image: Pandora Request]

Your WebView delegate methods are capturing all of the m.cdn* requests just fine, and all the rest are able to go through your custom protocol.

I would recommend doing any comparisons/alterations of outgoing web requests here:

`webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:`

since that appears to guarantee a call for all the requests you're using.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That IS where I am doing all of the request moderation.  The problem isn't that the request is not matching; the problem is that after it matches it never triggers the `canInitWithRequest:` of my custom protocol

Comment: Right, and my point was simply that requests to streaming services will not utilize NSURLProtocol. I'm happy to be proven wrong, though.

Comment: I don't see how that is possible.  `NSURLProtocol` has no way knowing whether or not it will be a stream request before the request is even initialized, right?